# How to recieve and store incomming messages in twilio using a java tomcat application?

Tags: java, twilio

Im using java and I'm successfully implemented twilio messaging API and now I can send messages from my application. I want to know How can I receive and store  messages if someone replies to that message.

Twilio Docs shows how to receive and set auto response but I'm not able to catch up.

[Twilio: Receiving Incoming Text Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/hello-monkey)

I'm only a few months experienced in java so any help is deeply appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Amal you can check out more fully featured examples in Java via Twilio tutorials. Like this one for example: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/marketing-notifications/java/servlets#3

Where this controller logic handles the incoming text message to do a couple things:

- If the texter is a person already in the database, parse the message
  they sent to see if it's a command we recognize.
- If it is a subscribe
  or unsubscribe command, update their subscription status in the
  database.
- If it is a command we don't recognize, send them a message
  explaining available commands.
- ```
  String output = "Sorry, we don't recognize that command. Available commands are: 'subscribe' or 'unsubscribe'.";

  if (message.startsWith(SUBSCRIBE_COMMAND) || message.startsWith(UNSUBSCRIBE_COMMAND)) {
      subscriber.setSubscribed(message.startsWith(SUBSCRIBE_COMMAND));
      repository.update(subscriber);
      if (!subscriber.isSubscribed())
          output = "You have unsubscribed from notifications. Textt 'subscribe' to start receiving updates again";
      else
          output = "You are now subscribed for updates.";
  }
  return output;
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the replay @meganspeir for that answer.